# CasperJS : Selecting an option in dropdown menu made of <div> and dynamic classes

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, web-crawler, casperjs

After many attempts and searches here, I can't help myself fixing my CasperJS script.

Basically, I'm crawling pages of a website that lists tons of pages. The main page can be filtered after I successfully logged in (this part is done) and then, I'd like to select in dropdown menu an option to filter them out. Here's the HTML code of the drop-down :

```
<div class="sg-dropdown brn-filters__status js-filter-status js-status-toggle">
  <div class="sg-dropdown__icon"></div>
  <div class="sg-dropdown__hole sg-dropdown__hole--inactive">
    <div class="sg-dropdown__item-text sg-dropdown__item-text--active js-main-status"> Unanswered </div>
    </div>
  <div class="sg-dropdown__hole  sg-dropdown__hole--active">
    <div class="sg-dropdown__item-text sg-dropdown__item-text--active"> Select </div>
    </div>
  <div class="sg-dropdown__items js-status-list">
    <div class="sg-dropdown__item-hole  ">
      <div class="sg-dropdown__item-text"> All </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sg-dropdown__item-hole  chosen-status">
      <div class="sg-dropdown__item-text"> Unanswered </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sg-dropdown__item-hole  ">
      <div class="sg-dropdown__item-text"> Unresolved </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sg-dropdown__item-hole  ">
      <div class="sg-dropdown__item-text"> Resolved </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I select "Resolved" in this drop-down menu using CasperJS?

***What I've noticed as potential clues:***

- By default, the filter "Unanswered" is applied (.js-main-status
  defines this I guess).
- Might be nothing relevant but as soon as I
  open the drop-down menu, the first `<div>` changes its class to
  `sg-dropdown brn-filters__status js-filter-status
  js-status-toggle--opened`
- When I select a filter (let's say "Resolved"), the `chosen-status` is added to its `sg-dropdown__item-hole` parent class. About this, `sg-dropdown__item-hole` finished with a double space, the last one being replaced by `chosen-status` when the option is clicked.

I've tried so many lines of code, from a simple `.click()` method to chunks of code more complex involving `evaluate()`, `sendKeys` (which I used right before to perform the login), `querySelector().selectedIndex`, `fetchText()` using XPath, and so on...

My problem, and it's on repeat with others buttons on this page, is that I have to deal with only `<div>` elements that have near-only classes that change as soon as an event is performed (click, scroll, etc).

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE #1**

I've tried these LOC (based on this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/casperjs/oG2ItwoLFjQ/9uzJxTPEAwAJ)):

```
casper.then(function () {
if (this.exists('div.sg-dropdown.brn-filters__status.js-filter-status.js-status-toggle')) {
  this.click('div.sg-dropdown.brn-filters__status.js-filter-status.js-status-toggle');
  console.log('click dropdown');    
}
else {
  console.log('no click dropdown');
}
});

casper.wait(9000, function() {
  console.log('wait 9 seconds 1/2');
});

casper.then(function() {
if (this.exist('div.sg-dropdown.brn-filters__status.js-filter-status.js-status-toggle.sg-dropdown--opened > div.sg-dropdown__items.js-status-list > div:nth-child(4)')) {
  this.click('div.sg-dropdown.brn-filters__status.js-filter-status.js-status-toggle.sg-dropdown--opened > div.sg-dropdown__items.js-status-list > div:nth-child(4)');
  console.log('click Resolved');
}
else {
  console.log('no click Resolved');
}
})

casper.wait(9000, function() {
  this.capture('test.png');
  console.log('wait 9 seconds 2/2');
})
```

The first step seems to work fine as I can see `wait 9 seconds 1/2` message prompted in the console. However, if I capture this step, I won't see the drop-down opened.

The second step is a complete failure. I first thought it was due to the absence of the `--opened` at the end of `sg-dropdown brn-filters__status js-filter-status js-status-toggle` class but nothing works as I got always this same error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'this.exist')

In some previous tests, I've returned the value `undefined` when I was trying to read ' Resolved' into the `<div>`. I even returned literally nothing in the console, like blank spaces and no error and the end of the run.

Any idea anyone?

**UPDATE #2**

I've just added an if condition to test `sg-dropdown brn-filters__status js-filter-status js-status-toggle--opened` class and it seems to not exist after clicking on the drop-down.

So step 1 is not even working and now, I'm kinda lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found this : https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/issues/1390 with a couple of links to Stack Overflow's threads often answered by @Artjom-b.

It seems that I'm in a dead end as CasperJS doesn't offer native support for selecting an option from a drop-down but in my case it's even worse as I have no `<select>` nor `<option>`. I'm sure there's a way to update the classes and reload the page consequently but it's way out of my league right now.

Anyway, I've found out another way to access the data I was looking for, I'm just digging now how to perform the scrapping faster!